# "When I return to Tokyo, we are going to visit the same places we visited on my birthday"

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, future

A German guy said this sentence was wrong:

> When I return to Tokyo, we are going to visit the same places **we visited on my birthday.**

He said you can't use the past to define **places** because the whole sentence is in the future.

What do you guys think?

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with the quoted sentence.

Comment: Did the "German guy" have an alternative in mind?

Answer (score 2):

No, that's completely correct English. I can't even figure out why your German friend would think that was wrong.

"In the future, you will visit some places. You have visited those places before." That meaning is unambiguously communicated by your sentence - there is no other way to read it.

It perhaps sounds a little clearer to say "We are going to visit the same places **which** we visited on my birthday", though.

Comment: I know right. It is a shame he's out there on grammar forums posting stuff  he doesn't know about misleading people.

Answer (score -1):

will visit the Colosseum in Rome next year. It was built during the Roman Empire and has hosted many gladiatorial games" is a correct sentence, because "was built" refers to a past event, the construction of the Colosseum. However, if the sentence is only focused on the current state of a place, it is best to use present tense. So, if someone says, "I will visit Paris next year. The Eiffel Tower was beautiful", it would be better to say, "The Eiffel Tower is beautiful".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).